# Twitter related issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am providing a facility where a user can tweet a content along with the url from my site (and it's working fine), but after tweeting from my site I am getting no response from twitter.

My question is how do my system will know whether user has posted on twitter or not?

It would be really great if someone could help me.

Comment: Twitter should respond to the API call.  I would check that no firewalls are blocking the response.